# How to rotate horizontally a text created by drawTextonPath in circle?

Tags: android, canvas, drawtext

I have a function that draws a text on a canvas with `drawTextOnPath`. I calculated offset everything works fine, but I want to draw it in a particular way. Currently texts rotation offset is equal to circles offset. I want to rotate the text by 90/45 degrees. But I can not figure out how.

Please any ideas.

```
private void drawLegend(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.rotate(-228, centerX, centerY);

    Path circle = new Path();
    double halfCircumference = (radius * 2 * Math.PI) - ((radius * 2 * Math.PI) / 8) * 2;
    double increments = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i <= this.mMaxSpeed; i += increments) {
        circle.addCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(String.format("%d", i),
                circle,
                (float) (i * halfCircumference / this.mMaxSpeed),
                -20f,
                scalePaint);
    }
    canvas.restore();
}
```

`This is current mapping`
[image: This is current mapping]

`Thi is how I wnat it to be displayed`
[image: Thi is how I wnat it to be displayed]

Comment: The way I would do it is by calculating the canvas position using the function for a circle and drawing the text that way.

Comment: @eski can you be more specific please? May be some example would help.

Comment: i have a text displayed just like 5 is displayed in your first image. i want it to be displayed like 25 is displayed in your first image. how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was not to draw using `drawTextOnPath` but to draw on a canvas using `drawText`

```
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(0), (x - width / 2) + 35, (y + height / 2) - 25, scalePaint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(5), (x - width / 2) - 20, (y) + 8, scalePaint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(10), (x - width / 2) + 30, (y - height / 2) + 40, scalePaint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(15), (x), (y - height / 2) - 18, scalePaint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(20), (x + width / 2) - 30, (y  - height / 2) + 40, scalePaint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(25), (x + width / 2) + 25, (y) + 8, scalePaint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(30), (x + width / 2) - 35, (y + height / 2) - 25, scalePaint);
```

**UPDATE after 7 months**

The secret was to use `sin` and `cos` functions to calculate offset by `x` and by `y`.

```
double theta = (7 * PI / 4) - (i * (2 * PI / 40));
double xPos = radiusScale * 1.2 * Math.sin(theta) + centerX - widthText / 2;
double yPos = radiusScale * 1.2 * Math.cos(theta) + centerY + heightText / 2;

canvas.drawText(textNotch, (float)xPos, (float)yPos, scalePaint);
```

Comment: i have a text displayed just like 5 is displayed in your first image. i want it to be displayed like 25 is displayed in your first image. how can i do that?

Comment: @SiddarthG check - *UPDATE after 7 months*

Comment: i dont want it a circular way. please check my question if you don't mind : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396437/how-to-rotate-text-drawn-in-a-straight-line-without-radius-when-using-drawtext

Comment: @Mikhail may you give some advice. I have used your solution, but I am getting all the values in one place and not across the arc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198812/add-values-to-arc